# Difference between rows and columns in input matrix

Tags: input, keras, deep-learning, bioinformatics

I am trying to build a gene expression autoencoder as part of my master's thesis. My professor recommended me to start small - to take 1 timepoint of a single sample gene expression and make a network that can represent it with fewer information (then expand this to timeseries and do some experiments).

So I have 19040 genes (or features) and 1 timepoint of 1 sample, that I need to feed into autoencoder. According to the theacher, my output layer should also be 19040.

What kind of input_shape should I have as input?

1. Input(shape=(1,19040))
2. Input(shape=(19040,1))
3. Input(shape=(19040,))

Is there a difference between 1 and 2 in my example?

```py
data  = pd.read_csv(filename, delimiter='\t', header=0)

data3d = array(data).reshape(5,19040,11)

x_train = keras.backend.transpose(data3d[0:1,:,1:2])

x = Dense(19040,activation = 'linear')(input_data)

encoded = Dense(10, activation='relu')(x)

decoded = Dense(19040, activation = 'linear')(encoded)

autoencoder = Model(input_data, decoded)
```

Edit:

Part of the data
[image: Data looks like this:]

First 19040 rows is 1 sample, then new one starts with same EntrezID (gene ID), and I have a total of 5 samples and 10 timepoints in the dataset.

Comment: What's your input data looks like? If you have 19040 features for one single sample, then you should use `Input(shape=(19040,))`.

Comment: Added part from data. And if I add more timepoint from data to training set, then it would be Input(shape=(19040,2))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct shape for your problem is choice (1):

```
Input(shape=(1,19040))
```

Keras models don't specify the sample dimension in the architecture specification - this is inferred from the actual dataset.  So, if I understand your situation, your input data will have this general shape:

(num_samples, num_time_steps, num_features)

but for now, num_samples=1, num_time_steps=1, and num_features=19040 which is consistent with choice (1) as mentioned earlier.

When you generalize to more time steps, you'll change to

```
Input(shape=(num_time_steps,19040))
```

Regarding the second part of your question, I believe the difference between choices (1) and (2) is that in choice (1) at each time step, you'll have every feature densely connected to every output node, where in choice (2), each time step will be a single feature connected to every node.

I hope this helps.